# Etymology of “weiter” and “wieder”

Tags: etymology

The words *weiter* and *wieder* are in the same semantic field (e.g. they can both be translated with different meanings of *again*). They also look similar. Are they etymologically related? How far?

In Swedish there is the word *vidare* that, given the sound changes, should be the exact cognate of *weiter*, and it also means the same. No idea though whether it dates back to Old Norse, or if it’s one of the many Low German loanwords (at least in the usage). Any other cognates, maybe in Low German (and maybe of *wieder*)?

Comment: Auch schwed. *vid*.

Comment: Yes, _vidare_ and _weiter_ are comparatives of _vid_ and _weit_. Unfortunately, SAOB (Dictionary of the Swedish Academy) hasn’t reached _vid_ yet; _vedersyn_ is the last word for now.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz wow really? That means also English *with*! 
But shouldn't *vid* mean something like "in front of"?

Comment: English *wide* is in the mix, *with* seems to be a bit more difficult. Btw, I know nothing, I just consulted dwds.de and etymonline.com.

Answer (score 7):

Most of the following information (if not indicated otherwise) is taken from **Duden - Band 7 - Das Herkunftswörterbuch**, the entries **weit** and **wider/wieder**:

The three German words *weit*, *wider* and *wieder* go back to the Indoeuropean root ** ̯ui-*, meaning *apart (auseinander)*.

The words *wider* and *wieder* come from a comparative ** ̯ui-t[e]ro-*, meaning *more apart, farther away*. The meaning developed to *against, towards (gegenüber, gegen)* and then to *again, back again (zurück, abermals)*. Until the 17th century there wasn't any difference in orthography between *wieder* and *wider*. Then some scholars started to use *wider* for the preposition and *wieder* for the adverb. As we can learn in this [Wiktionary entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/with#Etymology_1), English *with* and Swedish *vid* go back to the same root.

The word *weit* goes back to the compound root ** ̯ui-itós* with the adjectival meaning *diverged, gone apart (auseinandergegangen)*. The adjective *weiter* is (once again) a comparative of this compound; we can read on [Duden.de](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/weiter) that the adverb *weiter* is technically an adverbial comparative of *weit* (*"eigentlich adverbialer Komparativ von weit"*). As I understand it (and this is speculation), the meaning of the adverb shifted in phrases like *"Gehen wir weiter."* (=let's cover a greater distance) to *"Gehen/Machen wir weiter."* (=let's go on/continue). Thus, nowadays *weiter* does not only denote a greater distance but also the continuation of an action.